# Serialization. RiaServices.

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I've got three classes that are used in the ria-service:

First is Response class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ValidationResponseContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsWarning { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ConstraintName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Second is something like KeyValuePair<>:

```
[DataContract]
public class FieldValueContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ConstraintId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Third is request:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(FieldValueContainer))]
public class ValidationRequestContainer
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<FieldValueContainer> FieldValues { get; set; }

    public ValidationRequestContainer()
    {
        FieldValues = new List<FieldValueContainer>();
    }
}
```

After deploying my project I recieved an error in EventLog:

```
Exception System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[_2020vision.Infrastructure.FieldValueContainer,System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
```

What's wrong with my datacontract classes?

Comment: how does you fill FieldValues ? It looks like it's being reassigned with a LINQ query result before getting serialized (mark the set of FieldValues as "private" will somewhat enforce that FieldValues is actually a List<T>)

Comment: I'd check all the parts of my code and I sure that FieldValue is List<T>

Comment: ok, btw you lacks the AssociationAttribute on FieldValues and the corresponding reference and Fk field on FieldValueContainer. WCF Ria Associations are always sent to the wire as separated entity